# Black screen when attempting to run JavaFX based Android app

Tags: java, android, button, javafx, gluon

I just started (yesterday) developing Android apps through JavaFX, I'm on Eclipse using Gluon and it's being very weird.
I built the apk to the sample program provided by Gluon which is just a Label inside of a StackPane saying "Hello JavaFX World!" and thats it, it loads completely perfect on Android and on Desktop.
Now, I tried adding one button and it works perfectly fine on desktop but when I compile it to an apk and try to run it, it's just a black screen and I've tried waiting 10 minutes for it to load but nothing.

This is the code

```
package com.zach.csp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class APCS extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane(new Label("Hello JavaFX World!"));

    Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, visualBounds.getWidth(), visualBounds.getHeight());

    //Button b = new Button("sadsa");
    //root.getChildren().add(root);

    stage.getIcons().add(new Image(APCS.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    }
}
```

It's got to be the button too, because after I commented it out in the code above the program worked perfectly on my phone. Are buttons not supported on android or something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your commented out code says `root.getChildren().add(root);` Should it instead say `root.getChildren().add(b);`? Also, you may want to create the Scene after you finish adding items to the root.

Comment: You can create the Scene at the end or the beginning, at least in my experience on JFX in desktop its whatever your preference is. And thanks for showing me that, thats probably why it was a black screen I'm just blind, thank you.

Comment: Actually no, I fixed it and it still just displays a black screen. I dunno why this is happening.

Comment: Try to create a new Gluon Project via the Gluon Eclipse Plugin

Comment: A black screen might be an indication of an exception being thrown. Inspect the logcat output when running the application (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html).